# Installation problem - dual boot with W10 on Win certified laptop

Tags: boot, nvidia, intel, crash, nouveau

I've got Acer V15 Nitro Black Edition with Intel Integrated graphics + GTX 860M and I know there are some problems with drivers and so on. But I have problem with installation, where I just get spammed by nouveau errors over and over. Maybe after 1 min installation crashes and even if i get into live OS, system crashes during installation. I don't exactly know what's causing it, I turned off everything that was kind of blocking me... secure boot and different win certified stuff laptop. Can you help me sort out my problem ?

**Mr. cl-netbox advice helped me so much, thanks for everything man. Works as charm.**

Comment: Another Acer thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot When you boot are you using nVidia or Intel? And can you control which video mode is used for booting in UEFI settings or is it automatic? Nvidia needs nomodeset, but Intel needs different boot parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This was a long journey ... an answer in progress … and now finally … here is the answer !**

What you want is - more or less – a complete instruction on how to install Ubuntu alongside Windows. Please stay tuned - I will give you all advice necessary to get everything running!

So let's start …

First boot into your Windows installation and **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot**.
Disable hibernation by opening **command prompt as administrator** and execute:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

**Shut down** the machine **completely** – do **NOT reboot**!

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing**.
Press '**e**' and add **nouveau.modeset=0** to the **end** of the **linux line**, then press **F10**.

On the live desktop press the Windows key and type GParted into the search field.
Open **GParted** and reduce the Windows partition if there is no unallocated space.
Create **two new partitions** and format one with **ext4** - the other with **linux-swap**.

Now start the **Ubuntu installer** from the desktop and choose **Something else**.
Select the ext4 partition you have created before and choose `/` as mount point.
Select the same disk on which Windows is installed to install the bootloader to.

Start the Ubuntu installation process and when everything is completed, restart the computer.
Boot into BIOS and select Ubuntu in **UEFI settings** to be the default operating system to boot.
Now you are able to select the operating system you want to boot from the **GRUB boot menu**.

Boot Ubuntu installation and first of all install the most recent stable NVIDIA **graphics drivers**.

When the login screen appears press keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and the password and then execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Now you can boot into the desktop of the Ubuntu installation and start to customizing …

---

*Note:*

If you want to install Ubuntu to another disk, you can do so even if it is not recommended.
**Important** – **boot loader** has to be installed to the same **disk** where **Windows** is installed.

Comment: Im in installation process, is it possible to install ubuntu on different drive than windows and still have dual boot?

Comment: Thank you :) Is installation going to ask me where I want bootloader or do I have to do it manually somehow ?

Comment: @Axonis : You can see the boot loader installation location on the bottom of the Ubuntu installation partitioning screen - in most of all cases "sda" where Windows normally resides is already chosen. :)

Comment: Thanks again, got it. And I only need partitions ext4 with "/" and swap as big as RAM ? + Can I use common partition as storage for both win and ubuntu ?

Comment: @Axonis : yes - but what do you mean with common partition ? - If you mean one for personal data and similar things like backups you should format this with ntfs to make it accessible from both systems ! :)

Comment: Yeah great, already got ntfs. But other problem. If i boot laptop and dont press f12, windows automatically boots without giving me chance to choose. If i press f12 then choose grub then it gives me that purple screen with os choices

Comment: @Axonis : This is because every operating system has its own boot loader - you have to set Ubuntu to be the default system you want to boot in the BIOS (UEFI) settings to make it being a permanent solution. :)

Comment: I have already chosen grubx64.efi as main boot, but it seems like my laptop has this as default, to instantly boot to windows. If I just power up and then leave it, just Acer logo shows up and windows is booted. Also is it possible to use Gnome as default instead of Unity ?

Comment: @Axonis : I am really sorry that I cannot help you with this topic - the switch is hidden somewhere within your Acer BIOS settings (I'm sure you will find it ...) - bust most important : I am so glad that we got your system up and running ... so ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Comment: Found it and did it, but now I have different problem, after I boot up Ubuntu from Grub it just goes black and sometimes flashes terminal wanting me to log in.

Comment: @Axonis : Uninstall all NVIDIA software you have had installed before.  

- When login screen appears press Ctrl + Alt + F1  

- Enter user name and password and then execute:

    sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  nvidia-prime
    sudo reboot

- Now re-install the drivers - repeat the procedure ...

- When login screen appears press Ctrl + Alt + F1  

- Enter user name and password and then execute:

    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
    sudo reboot ! :)

Comment: Now it just restars as soon as I hit enter choosing Ubuntu, I think I better reinstall whole system.

Comment: @Axonis : When you reinstall the system I suggest that you re-format the / (root) partition with ext4 using GParted before ... I mean the Ubuntu partition ... then follow exactly the instructions given in the answer !

Comment: Sure, will do, if I use Ubuntu gnome it wont affect repositaries I can use or does it ?

Comment: @Axonis : Everything is the same with Ubuntu GNOME - it is only another desktop environment. :)