# Blank screen Ubuntu 15.04 update with NVIDIA driver (nomodeset does not work)

Tags: nvidia, updates

After updating to Ubuntu 15.04, the screen goes blank when I boot Ubuntu with grub2. I have tried most of the posted solutions (adding nomodeset, changing quiet splash to no splash) but to no avail. What can I do? (I can't access ubuntu's terminal, but I do have access to Windows10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password.

Identify your NVIDIA graphics hardware by executing:

```
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

Uninstall every NVIDIA related software by executing:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password.

Install the NVIDIA drivers by executing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-*
sudo reboot
```

Note 1:

As you did not provide any information about your NVIDIA graphics card check [drivers versions](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx?lang=en-us).
Replace * with the latest stable main version number (e.g. 355) that supports your NVIDIA GPU.

Note 2:

When you have switchable graphics cards install nvidia-prime (NVIDIA Optimus support) as well.

Note 3:

If you ever have had bumblebee installed before to switch between graphics - also remove this.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried adding nouveau.modeset=0 and the screen remain blank after booting. I can't seem to access the login screen.

Comment: @KevinLiang : Maybe something serious went completely wrong while performing the upgrade process ... Make a clean install of Ubuntu 15.10 and after having finished, follow the instructions ... Ubuntu 15.04 will be unsupported soon anyway ! :)

Comment: should it look like this? linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-15-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=df64fe7e-52dd-4529-a9cb-c9df63503f96 ro quiet splash $vt_handoff nouveau.modeset=0

Comment: @KevinLiang : yes - but I wonder about this kernel you use ... Ubuntu 15.04 has kernel 3.19 ... :)

Comment: How do I figure this out? does this affect the code?

Comment: additionally, is there a way to do a clean install of Ubuntu 15.10 without erasing my data?

Comment: @KevinLiang : As I said before ... a clean install is the best option - backup your data to another disk or partition before and restore it back after having finshed the installation. :)

Comment: Hi cl-netbox, sorry but I am quite unfamiliar with the Ubuntu environment. How do I "partition before and restore it back". I have a dual-boot, so can I do this on Windows 10?

Comment: @KevinLiang : This is an instruction that explains everything to you : http://askubuntu.com/questions/693491/installation-problem-dual-boot-with-w10-on-win-certified-laptop/693509#693509 and the most easiest way to save your data is by copying it to another drive and paste it back after you have completed the installation. :)

Comment: Hi Cl-netbox, thank you for your help! I did a clean install of Ubuntu on a new partition. Given that I cannot access my old Ubuntu (and therefore its content), is there a way I can move the files from the old partition to the new partition while I am using the newly installed Ubuntu? (the guides I find involve being in the old partition and mounting the new partition, but i can't access the old partition)

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did. I mounted the old partition in my new ubuntu and I can access and see the files fine. Do I then just use cp in my command line? (i.e. sudo cp /media/oldpartition  /media/Computer)

Comment: @KevinLiang : Using the terminal is one possibility ... another one is to use a file manager ... but this would be a new question - most of all I am very glad that you solved the problem and are having the new system running ... enjoy ubuntu experience ! :)

Comment: `nouveau.modeset=0` didn't work for me - I'm in the same situation.